# How to solve an unresolved external symbol error in Visual Studio project that references an Oracle C library?

Tags: c, visual-studio, static-libraries, oracleclient

I have a simple VS project that contains a Sample.c generated by a Pro*C compiler. This file doesn't do any thing fancy, it just try to connect to an Oracle database.

I'm getting the following error message:

> unresolved external symbol _sqlcxt referenced in function _main OracleProC

[image]

I came a cross couple of posts and they all suggested to:

1. To add the folder containing the .lib files under
   Linker-->General:-->Additional Library Directories
   [image]
2. Specify the lib in that folder that I'm linking by going to
   Linker-->Input-->Additional Dependencies
   [image]

Despite having these set, I'm still getting the error message.

Comment: Add your directiory under Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories

Comment: @Irelia I did, I got the same error message.

Comment: Are you compiling your project for the correct architecture of your linked libraries?